# Convert all the elements to string irrespective of datatype

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am consuming  lot of elements(Fields)  from webservice response. Most of the  elements  datatypes are `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger`, `xmlGregorianCalender`, `String`, `int` etc not collections.

My requirement is i need to write a utility method that should return a string value irrespective of type.

I googled everywhere but i was unable to  find the solution.
Please guide me to achieve this.

I tried the following based on reply's.But i am not getting the  proper output

```
    BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(10);
    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger("12334");
    String sampleStr1 = ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(big);
    String sampleStr2 = ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(bigInt);
    System.out.println("big::"+sampleStr1+"::bigint::"+sampleStr2);
```

Output :

```
big::java.math.BigDecimal@2afa3ac1[intVal=    <null>,scale=0]::bigint::java.math.BigInteger@72291aff[signum=1,mag={12334},bitCount=0,bitLength=0,lowestSetBit=0,firstNonzeroIntNum=0]
```

Expected output :

```
big::10::bigint::12334
```

Comment: For a lot of those Objects you can utilize their `toString()` method.

Comment: @Trobbins thank you for your reply. cannot get you.Could you please post a example i am new to java.Also sometimes .toString() will return object instead of value of string.

Comment: `toString()` always returns a `String`.

Comment: I edited my comment sorry for the mistake.

Comment: JSON (eg google GSON lib) is very easy to implement . it converts objects to json -string

Comment: @SrinathGanesh thank you for your reply.In my project i don't have access to GSON lib that's why i tagged this question only to java & Apache commans.Also i don't want to convert it to json strings.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Would the `toString()` method suffice. It should be implemented on all classes and should produce the best summary of the object in question.

Otherwise, you could create your own wrappers of these objects and convert the to JSON or XML using Jackson or JAXB

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html).reflectionToString() available in apache commons library.

Sample Code:

```
public class Test {
  BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(10);
  BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger("12334");

  public String toString() {
    **ToStringBuilder.setDefaultStyle(ToStringStyle.SIMPLE_STYLE);**
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test test = new Test();
    System.out.println(test);
  }
}
```

Returns response in the format:

```
Class@ObjectAddress[field=value,..]
Test@1f4e8ac9[big=10,bigInt=12334]
```

Setting the above style would give just the values as

```
10,12334
```

I have overridden toString() to get finer control. I am not sure how to correct the output with direct access to Integer/BigDecimal.

Comment: could you please post a sample example of converting wrapper classes(BigDecimal & BigInteger) to string.Also it will really work for xmlGregorianCalender??

Comment: public class Test {
  BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(10);
  BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger("12334");

  public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test test = new Test();
    System.out.println(test);
  }
}

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30106636/edit) your post to add the proper code there. Use comments to reply to other people only.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Thanks. I am getting use to the process. Appreciate your comment.

Comment: @jags thank you for posting the code.But i want to write it as a utility method.I edited my post with code i tried based on your example but i am not getting proper output.Could you please correct me.